# Suggestion for writing more modular and testable iOS app using Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, ios

I am writing an app for iOS devices using Objective C.

It seems the code written are tightly coupled and reuse is very difficult.

Any suggestion for writing more modular iOS app using Objective C? Especially easy to test.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

some more suggestions, which i see as common problems in objc programs:

- favor protocols over subclassing more than the average objc developer does (very important)
- favor smaller objects, which are more specialized
- minimize global objects (e.g singletons)
- reuse and test often
- realize and embrace the dynamic nature of objc types/runtime. don't just apply/approximate the idioms of your most familiar language to objc. chances are, your programs will suffer.
- for code reuse/backend: favor C, C++, apple's distributed types, and protocols
- stub out packages/sub-libraries in nontrivial programs. these should build independently.
- be mindful of what you are re-implementing, and move the common implementation to a library
- keep libraries small, focused, and be mindful of their dependencies. also write with the expectation that the library may be used in many contexts. keep the warnings low, the public interfaces simple, and use nice lengthy descriptive names and prefixes to avoid clashes in the flat namespace.

Answer (score 2):

You should be writing object-oriented code; all the standard best practices for writing modular, re-usable, testable objects apply just as much in Objective C as in any other language.

Is there some reason you believe that Objective C is different in this regard?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some suggestions:

- Try to put reusable components as separate library sub-projects. XCode can handle projects within projects.
- Use categories to extend or modify behaviour of built-in classes. Components are isolated from the rest of your code and very easy to test
- Make sure you follow the MVC pattern and don't bloat the controllers. Put application logic in your model classes so they don't have dependencies to the views, which makes it difficult to test.