# Mock server response unit testint

Tags: ios, unit-testing

i am building a unit test in my app, there is a section the method need to call `GET` request to retrieve some numbers like this :

```
http://api.mycompany/numbers
```

this call return a `JSON` object with random numbers. so i want to mock when the device trying to call this address it will not actually make a call and i will return a response that is predefined, i am new to unit testing and i am really like to get some ideas and main concepts of how to manage unit test scenarios.
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't give a better answer than what has [already](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/153410/what-are-the-design-principles-that-promote-testable-code-designing-testable-c) been [written](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576698/suggestion-for-writing-more-modular-and-testable-ios-app-using-objective-c). Learn the concepts of SOLID code and more testable, maintainable software will result. The [Apple sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UnitTests/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011742) is pretty good as a starting point.